# Moving Label in MAUI moves not properly

Tags: c#, maui

I am writing an app in which a card with content X similar to Tinder displays X+1 by swiping right or X-1 by swiping left.

The moving of the label I have with

```
lbl.TranslationX = translateLeft -= 10; //for swiping left
```

implemented.

Actually it works exactly as it should but after each swipe in one direction the speed in which the swipe animation is displayed gets faster. Until finally it is not visible anymore.
Most likely I am doing something wrong with the timer.
Can someone please help me?

Mainpage.xaml.cs

```
namespace MAUI_SwipeExample;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private List<string> strings = new List<string>();
    private int translateRight = 0;
    private int translateLeft = 0;
    private IDispatcherTimer timer;
    private double centerX;
    private double centerY;
    private int listLength;
    private int pos = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = Dispatcher.CreateTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMicroseconds(300);
        centerX = lbl.X;
        centerY = lbl.Y;
        strings.Add("ONE");
        strings.Add("TWO");
        strings.Add("THREE");
        strings.Add("FOUR");
        strings.Add("FIVE");
        listLength = strings.Count;
        lbl.Text = strings[0];
    }

    private void OnSwiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e) {
        switch (e.Direction) {
            case SwipeDirection.Left:
                timer.Tick += MoveLeft;
                timer.Start();
                lbl.Text = strings[pos];
                pos--;
                if (pos == -1) {
                    pos = 4;
                }
                break;
                case SwipeDirection.Right:
                timer.Tick += MoveRight;
                timer.Start();
                lbl.Text = strings[pos];
                pos++;
                if(pos == listLength ) {
                    pos = 0;
                }
                break;
            case SwipeDirection.Up:
                break;
            case SwipeDirection.Down:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void MoveLeft(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        lbl.TranslationX = translateLeft -= 10;
        if (translateLeft == 100) {
            timer.Stop();
            lbl.IsVisible = false;
            lbl.TranslateTo(centerX, centerY);
            translateLeft = 0;
            lbl.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }


    private void MoveRight(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        lbl.TranslationX = translateLeft -= 10;
        if(translateRight == 100) {
            timer.Stop();
            lbl.IsVisible = false;
            lbl.TranslateTo(centerX, centerY);
            translateRight = 0;
            lbl.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Mainpage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MAUI_SwipeExample.MainPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label BackgroundColor="Aqua"
               Margin="0,25,0,0"
               x:Name="lbl"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="30"
               WidthRequest="250"
               HeightRequest="500">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left" Swiped="OnSwiped"/>
                <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Right" Swiped="OnSwiped"/>
                <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Up" Swiped="OnSwiped"/>
                <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Down" Swiped="OnSwiped"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

During my search I have already found the following.

[Swipe Card Game](https://github.com/markolazic88/SwipeCardView)

But would like to do it with just moving a UI object.

Comment: You add MoveLeft and MoveRight to the timer, but you never remove them. So they get called twice the second time, three times the third time, etc.

Comment: if you create separate times for Left and Right, then you can just start/stop them as needed, without having to set the event handlers each time

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. Just added -= MoveRight and -= MoveLeft

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question-asker described in a comment how they solved it.